# JHipster i18n issue: translation-not-found in user activation page and password reset page

Tags: internationalization, jhipster

My JHipster i18n works if users access it from the login page and it works fine after the users login. However, if the user click the link in the activation email to activate the account, i18n is not working because translation-not-found is shown for all jhiTranslate elements.

For example, when user receives the following email:
Your bbb account has been created, please click on the URL below to access it:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/reset/finish?key=01225838052842547789

and the user click the above link, the page is like
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYSkJ.png)
Then, I found this translation-not-found problem exists for all the pages open with an URL directly, except the login page.
For example, if I open the "forgot password" from the login page, i18n works fine. However, if I use the same URL http://localhost:8080/#/reset/request directly in the browser, translation-not-found appears everywhere.

May I know if anyone had similar JHipster i18n issues and how to fix this? Thanks.

My JHipster version is 4.8.2 and I use English and French in my project.

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade to latest JHipster 4.14.5?

Comment: Not yet, I believe it shouldn't be a JHipster version issue since no one complained about this error in JHipster github

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue

Code:

```
add import { JhiLanguageService } from 'ng-jhipster';
```

and in the constructor `private languageService: JhiLanguageService` in the `PasswordResetFinishComponent`. With this it solved the problem